# Low-level sending of mail from file via cmdline

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I have a saved mail (in Maildir format) including all headers and attachments.

I would like to send this file as email (with all the given headers intact) to a new email address, something like:

> `$ cat mail.txt  |` *forwardMail* `test@example.com`

which should basically connect to the MTA, use `test@example.com` as the "RCPT TO" and the contents of `mail.txt` as the DATA.

I tried things like the following, but it doesn't handle headers and attachments gracefully; also, I have to specify the subject on the cmdline (while it is already defined in `mail.txt`).

```
 $ cat mail.txt | mail -s "foo" test@example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the message into `/usr/lib/sendmail -i`. (Some systems put it in `/usr/sbin/sendmail` instead.)

All MTAs (Postfix, Sendmail MTA, Exim, &c.) install their own version of the `sendmail` program, and it is the same tool that Mail and other Unix programs use to submit mail messages.

- The recipient addresses are specified in the command line. (If you add `-t` instead, `sendmail` takes the recipients from the message's headers such as To:, which you do not want this time, but it might be useful in other cases.)
- The `-i` option tells `sendmail` to disable the special treatment of lines starting with a dot; it is needed for historical reasons.
- The `-f $address` option can be used to change the "envelope FROM" address (not related to the From: header).